# EPI2ME cannot detect my installed WSL, Java and Docker

Tags: java, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would really appreciate some help in launching EPI2ME. I have already installed WSL 2, Java and Docker desktop prior to downloading EPI2ME. I tried launching EPI2ME but it seems to not be able to detect WSL, Java and Docker. I have already tried disabling my firewall but to no avail. Thank you
I tried updating, and disabling firewall but to no avail